# "had to have known" vs "must know"

Tags: word-choice

> Coroner just told me that Christine's body was put in the water sometime early Tuesday morning.
>   So that Monday night party is critical.
>   Somebody there had to have known what happened later that night.

Why did the author not simply say:

> ... Somebody there must know what happened later that night.

What does the original sentence convey that mine doesn't ?
or, What does the original sentence not convey that mine does ?

Thank you

Comment: The first sentence means somebody must have known at the time it happened. Yours just means that somebody must know *now*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you. 
But now I have another question: Wouldn't a detective be more interested in a person who knows _now_ vs a person who knew on Monday night but is inaccessible now (because of death or flight out of the country or ...) ?
Hence, I feel my sentence better reflects the usefulness of a person who knows now.

Comment: The gist of the dialogue is that the detective is saying it's not really possible for somebody *not* to have known what happened the night it happened. (Somebody had to have seen it.) The detective needs to find that person and question them. You might feel better replacing *known* with *seen*, but the tense amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks. Now I've understood the reason why the detective used "had to have known"

Comment: **had to have known** and **must have known** are the same thing. You need a past tense.

Answer (score 1):

To consolidate some comments I had made on this.

> Somebody there ***had to have known*** what happened that night.

This means that somebody must have known at the time it happened.

> Somebody there ***must know*** what happened later that night.

This means that somebody must know *now*.

---

The choice of tense is a matter of personal choice. There's no reason why *must know* couldn't be used—but there's also no reason why it *must* be used.

However, do note that if it's actually talking about somebody knowing in the present, either *there* would be dropped or it would be *somebody **who was** there*. It's unlikely that the person who was there that night is still there.

---

Consider what happens when you replace *know* with *see*:

> Somebody there ***had to have seen*** what happened that night.

This expresses the fact that it's not really possible for somebody to have *not* seen what happened the night it happened. In this case, the detective needs to find that person (the one who *saw* it) it and question them.

Although the specific verb is different, the verb tense in *had to have known* is being used in the same way. You can also think of *had to have known* as *had to have been aware of*.

Comment: I've never suspected that the word "there" is contributing to the correct meaning and is a substitute to the long "somebody who was there" !!  This is really new to me. I thought it was a short for "out there"

Comment: I can think of one case where the difference in meaning might in fact be important, actually.  The detective might be remarking that somebody must have known *some time ago*, e.g. the last time the police questioned the witnesses, but did not come forward, and the detective's question is why didn't they come forward?  Who were they shielding?    I've no idea whether this is applicable to the plot of the book in question, of course, but I can imagine it being possible.

Comment: @A.B. You might well be right. I can see your suggestion matching the situation, as a first questioning did happen at the moment the detective said the sentence. For more info, this sentence is said by agent Lisbon, 18:50 into episode 01x03 of "The Mentalist". Thank you for the follow up.